# Matlab create window on image

Tags: matlab

I need to create A 16X16 window to scan over an entire image in matlab and record the position and grey level value of pixel with largest grey level in window.

Can anyone guide me on how to do this? Cant find any help on creating windows on images.

Thanks

Comment: So, the position vector would be of a length same as the number of pixels right? Because it's for every pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old school for-Loop method -

```
%%// Outputs that you are interested in are - img, x1 and y1
img = rgb2gray(input_image); %%// Gray level values
x1 = zeros(size(img)); %%// Row values for the maximum pixel in the 16x16 window
y1 = zeros(size(img)); %%// Column values for the maximum pixel in the 16x16 window
for k1= 1:size(img,1)-15
    for k2= 1:size(img,2)-15
        img1 = img(k1:k1+15,k2:k2+15);        
        [val,ind1] = max(img1(:));
        img(k1+8,k2+8)=val; %%// Store the max grey value into the image
        [x1(k1,k2),y1(k1,k2)] = ind2sub([16 16],ind1);
    end
end
```

**Edit 1:** For calculating mean across this sliding window, use this -

```
window_size = 16; %%// Edit this to your window size

wsz = window_size-1;
mp = round(window_size/2);

%%// Outputs that you are interested in are - img, x1 and y1
img = rgb2gray(input_image); %%// Gray level values
x1 = zeros(size(img)); %%// Row values for the maximum pixel in the 16x16 window
y1 = zeros(size(img)); %%// Column values for the maximum pixel in the 16x16 window

img1 = img;
for k1= 1:size(img,1)-wsz
    for k2= 1:size(img,2)-wsz
        window_data = img(k1:k1+wsz,k2:k2+wsz);        
        val = round(mean(window_data(:)));
        img1(k1+mp,k2+mp)=val; %%// Store the mean grey value into the image
    end
end

figure,imshow(img1)
```

**Edit 2:**

```
img1 = Z;
for k1= 1:size(Z,1)-wsz
    for k2= 1:size(Z,2)-wsz
        window_data = Z(k1:k1+wsz,k2:k2+wsz);        
        val = mean(window_data(:))
        if (val~=0)
            keyboard;
            error('Look, there is a non-zero mean value!');
        end
       % img1(k1+mp,k2+mp)=val; %%// Store the mean grey value into the image
        display(val);
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you  explain to me why you subtract 15 from the length of the row in cols?

Comment: @user1853871 Because you are sliding with a window of size 16 and k1 and k2 denote the starting indices along row and column.

Comment: ah ok! Thanks. So if I am working with a 32x32 window, I simply subtract 31?

Comment: Yes! But this is for a sliding window case, please remember that.

Comment: Thanks, A sliding window is exactly what i need!

Comment: Im trying to modify this to get the mean of the pixel value instead of getting the largest pixel and location of it. However I cannot get it work as it is just returning zeros. Can you explain what I neeed to do?

Comment: @user1853871 Check out Edit 1.

Comment: thanks for this however I do display (val) to view the mean for each window they are all 0

Comment: just to clarify, i do not want to apply a mean filter to the image, i just want to obtain the mean intensity value of the pixels within the image and display it.

Comment: @user1853871 I have double-checked, it's printing `val` as non-zero values on many occassions.

Comment: @user1853871 Are you sure that you are reading image data properly, like this? - `input_image = imread(image_filename);`

Comment: if I upload my code would you be able to have a look?

Comment: Sure, would have a look!

Comment: Thanks! This is my image: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/F2pMsWKgT/ and my matlab file: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/F2pMsWKgT/. This code is at the very bottom of the file

Comment: The `matlab file link` goes to the image link.

Comment: It says `Invalid Download Link`. Could you double check?

Comment: this link seems to be working for me but try this one: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/U8pA9p58oR/DetectROI.m.html

Comment: Ran it just now and it is printing a lot of values, many are zero because its a mammogram image, but there are quite many non-zero values too. To see those you can insert this right after `val` is calculated - `if (val~=0), keyboard; end`. The execution would halt when `val` is non-zero, which you can print and see it for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. When I run it, every value is 0, there are no non-zero values.

Comment: @user1853871 Check out Edit 2.

Comment: thanks, tried this but the error is not showing as there are no non-zero values

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here is another way of achieving this: store the intensity and the position of the maximum in your window as the real and imaginary parts of a complex number. You can then use the `nfilter` function to perform the moving filtering:

```
fun = @(x) complex(double(max(x(:))),double(find(x==max(x(:)), 1, 'first')));
B = nlfilter(YourImage,[16 16],fun);
```

You can then access the maximum and its position from the complex map. Here is an example of the results when applied to one of the images given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804853/counting-the-squama-of-lizards):

Max intensity in the neighborhood (`imagesc(real(B))`):

[image]

Position of the maximum (`imagesc(img(B))`):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
% img = [matrix representing your image]

N = 16;

window = repmat(struct, ceil(size(img, 1) / N), ceil(size(img, 2) / N));
for row = 1:N:size(img, 1)
    for col = 1:N:size(img, 2)
        r = (row - 1) / N + 1;
        c = (col - 1) / N + 1;

        imgWindow = img(row:min(end,row+N-1), col:min(end,col+N-1));
        largest = max(imgWindow(:));
        [rLarg, cLarg] = find(imgWindow == largest, 1, 'first');

        window(r, c).largest = largest;
        window(r, c).row = rLarg + row - 1;
        window(r, c).col = cLarg + col - 1;
    end
end
```

You'll have a matrix called **window** where **window(r,c)** contains information about window (r,c), with the fields:

- **window(r,c).largest:** gray level of the largest pixel
- **window(r,c).row, window(r,c).col:** position of the largest pixel on the original image

Comment: You're welcome. One thing I forgot to mention is this: if there are two or more largest pixels (all with the same gray level), the code will pick the first one for row/col coordinates, using sequencial indexing. If you want the coordinates of them all, just change the **find** line to `find(window == largest);` and now row/col will be vectors with the coordinates of all largest pixels in each window.

Comment: thanks, couild you just explain to me what r = (row - 1) / N + 1;
   c = (col - 1) / N + 1; does?

Comment: Sure. Suppose your image is 48x48 pixels. Therefore, there are 3x3 windows. Variables **row** and **col** in both for's will assume the values 1, 17 and 33, which are the starting position of each window. That two lines you asked will translate those to 1, 2 and 3, respectively, which are the indexes of each window.

Comment: thanks. I am now confused about the next step in my alogrithm... IF pixels surrounding the largest pixel are as bright as the
largest pixel grey level value
AND outer pixels are darker than the largest pixel grey
level value
THEN largest pixel position is the center pixel of an ROI. Can you explain to me how to start by getting the pixels surrounding the largest pixel?

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm new on Stackoverflow, but I think you should ask this by creating another question, because it's a new problem.

Comment: ok :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862387/matlab-find-surrounding-pixels-and-outer-pixels

Answer (score 0):

The key step you need is to extract a sub image the given scanning window (i.e. rectangle area). If the scanning winow, say `roi` is in format `[x, y, width, height]`, you can simply call [`imcrop`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcrop.html):

```
subImage = imcrop(Image, roi);
```

Then you can find the max gray level in the sub image, like this

```
[value, location] = max(subImage(:));
```

Of course, you need to update the scanning window i.e. `roi` in order to scan over the whole image.

Comment: Thanks what do the X and Y stand for in roi?

Comment: i am unsure of how to move the window along so that it scans the whole image