# design my own 2d filter--matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm wondering is there a way to define my own 2d filter. Assuming there is a matrix A, I'd like to assign every element of A to the maximum value of its 8 neighbors. For example:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5
     6 7 8 9 10
     -1 3 4 8 13
     4 2 0 9 1]
```

After filtering:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5
     6 8 9 10 10
     -1 8 9 13 13
     4 2 0 9 1]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may use [**`imdilate`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) to get you the maximum of a 9x9 neighbhorhood -

```
%%// Dilate to get the max of a 9x9 neighborhood (including the element itself)
A1 = imdilate(A, true(3));

%%// Since you are looking to keep the boundary elements
m1 = ones(size(A));
m1(2:end-1,2:end-1)=0;
A1 = m1.*A+~m1.*A1
```

If you are looking to get the maximum of a 8x8 neighbhorhood, i.e. exclude the element itself, use a modified kernel for use into `imdilate` -

```
%%// Dilate to get the max of a 8x8 neighborhood (excluding the element itself)
h = true(3);
h(2,2)=false;
A1 = imdilate(A,h);

%%// Since you are looking to keep the boundary elements
m1 = ones(size(A));
m1(2:end-1,2:end-1)=0;
A1 = m1.*A+~m1.*A1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an arbitrary filter with `nlfilter`, an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22818561/2777181). In your case:

```
fun = @(x) max(x(:)),
B = nlfilter(YourImage,[3 3],fun);
```

In the case that you want to exclude the center pixel, replace `fun` by something like:

```
fun=@(x) max([x(1:3, 1)' x(1,2) x(3,2) x(1:3,3)'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following syntax and use ordfilt2 as a maximum filter:

```
B = ordfilt2(A, 9, ones(3,3))
```

Here is a doc page for [ordfilt2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ordfilt2.html).