# Proper way of accessing field of a 1xn stuct

Tags: matlab, struct, cell-array

I have looked for the proper way to access a given field of a struct and the manual and online searches didn't help.

Formally, let `MyStruct` be a 1xn `struct` variable. It's easy to list all the elements stored in a field with:

```
MyStruct.Thisfield   
ans =
    0.7010

ans =
    0.310

ans =
    0.444
```

etc.

Now the only way I found to be able to access an element of this is to use a temporary variable, e.g. `temp={MyStruct.Thisfield}` and then `temp{1,2}` etc. I think it's clumsy but can't figure out what else to do.

This:

```
>> MyStruct{1,1}.Thisfield
```

> Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

and this:

```
>> MyStruct.Thisfield{1,1}
```

> Field reference for multiple structure elements that is followed by
>   more reference blocks is an error.

are my unsuccessful attempts.

See an example *in situ* in this answer of mine https://stackoverflow.com/a/22813577/2777181

Comment: Have you tried `MyStruct(2).Thisfield` ?

Comment: Note that the curly brackets are (only) for handling cells. `MyStruct(1,1).Thisfield` would have also done the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you currently do:

```
temp={MyStruct.Thisfield}
temp{1,2}
```

You can replace this by directly accessing the second element of the struct (As also mentioned by @Jucestain):

```
MyStruct(2).Thisfield
```

---

Note that in one dimensional calls, you don't need to specify all dimensions. So in your original code you could have done

```
temp{2}
```